# how to avoid the for loop in R to traverse the variables of a dataframe

Tags: r

In a dataframe I want to add a new variable and calculate the values by applying a function to which I pass the value of one of the already existing variables as a parameter

I mean, I start from this dataframe
[image: df de base]

and I'm only capable of doing it like this

```
contratado<-function(proyectoID){
sql<-paste0("SELECT  SUM(Detalle.LineTotal) AS Importe
FROM    FULCRUM.dbo.RDR1 AS Detalle INNER JOIN
    FULCRUM.dbo.ORDR AS Cabecera ON Detalle.DocEntry = Cabecera.DocEntry INNER JOIN
    FULCRUM.dbo.OPRJ AS Proyectos ON Detalle.Project = Proyectos.PrjCode
WHERE Cabecera.DocStatus = \'o\' AND Detalle.Project=",dbQuoteString(con,proyectoID))
return (dbGetQuery(con,sql))
}

SumaContratado<-function(df){
for (indiceFila in 1:nrow(df)) {
  df[indiceFila,ncol(df)]<-contratado(df$ProyectoID[indiceFila])
}
return(df)
```

}

```
df<-df%>%
mutate(Contratado=0)

df <- SumaContratado(df)
```

But I assume that using sapply or map you should be able to avoid that for loop row by row but I am not able to figure out how to make it work.

Any idea please?

Regards

Comment: `dbGetQuery`'s `statement` parameters accepts only arguments of length 1, i.e. a single SQL query. This is the limiting factor here, so you will need to create some kind of loop.

Comment: The loop is in SumaContratado function where row by row I call to contratado function passing it ha value of df$ProyectoID. This is what I thought was possible with some kind of sapply or map

Comment: `df$sql_result <- sapply(df$ProyectoID, contratado)` should work.